# Trouble with sending post data with correct info

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to send post data with these headers:

```
User-Agent: MBAM-C
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: True
Content-Length: 619
Connection: Close
```

I originally utilized the requests library, however, it automatically added headers onto the request such as `Accept-Encoding` etc.

I am now attempting to utilize urllib on python 3.x, this is my post data:

```
{
"IsLocationTrue": "True",
"LocType": "country"
}
```

And thats exactly how it should be sent, **NOT** urlencoded.
However when I set this as the data, but it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I have tried making the whole thing a string with `"""`, however, of course, I got an error that it cannot be a string.

After that I just simply attempted to encode the string, this made the script run, however when I analyze the request, no data is sent in the post data.

I dont know what else to try, help.

PS. I am on python 3.x and utilizing the urllib.request library.

Comment: show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending this:

```
postdata=b'''{"IsLocationTrue":"True","LocType":"country"}'''
```

Comment: Still, no post data is sent, it correctly sets the headers and does everything else but doesnt send the data in the post data, just empty